# Code for a platform moving back and Forth

Tags: phaser-framework

I'am trying to make a game where the character can jump on a platform that's moving Horizontally, once the platform reaches a specific point it comes back and it repeats. However I have had some trouble finding the correct way to write the code for this I tried using setVelocityX() is looks like this

```
var movingPlatform = {

  moveRight : function(){
    platforms.setVelocityX(100)
  },
  moveleft : function(){
     platforms.setVelocityX(-100);
    }
  }

  var move = true;

  if(move = true){
    movingPlatform.moveRight()
  }

  if(move = false){
    movingPlatform.moveleft();
  }


 if(platforms.x <= platformMinX){
   move = true;       
  }

  if(platforms.x >= platformMaxX){
    move = false;         
  }
```

all this did was when the platform reaches the 'platformMaxX' point it just moved back and forth in that area so 'movingPlatform.moveRight()' is still being called

Answer (score 0):

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,    loader: {
      baseURL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nazimboudeffa/assets/master/',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade'
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
var dude;
var alien1, alien2;
var direction = 1

function preload ()
{
  this.load.image('dude', 'sprites/phaser-dude.png');
  this.load.image('alien1', 'sprites/phaser-alien.png');
  this.load.image('alien2', 'sprites/alien2.png');
}

function create ()
{ dude = this.physics.add.sprite(300, 100, 'dude');
  alien1 = this.physics.add.sprite(400, 100, 'alien1');
  alien1.body.immovable = true;
  alien2 = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 100, 'alien2');
  alien2.body.immovable = true;
}

function update ()
{
  this.physics.add.collider(dude, alien1, flipX, null, this);
  this.physics.add.collider(dude, alien2, flipX, null, this);
  dude.setVelocityX(direction * 100)
}

function flipX ()
{
  direction = - direction
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.18.1/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,    loader: {
      baseURL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nazimboudeffa/assets/master/',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade'
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
  this.load.image('dude', 'sprites/phaser-dude.png');
}

function create ()
{ 
  this.dude = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 100, 'dude');

  const tween = this.tweens.add({
    targets: this.dude,
    x: 300,
    ease: 'Power0',
    duration: 3000,
    flipX: true,
    yoyo: true,
    repeat: -1,
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.19.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried the tween variable the platform did move back and forth but when my player jumps on the platform he doesnt move along with the platform